# PHP SQLite Login System Validity

Tags: php, sql, sqlite, authentication, system

I myself have been trying at this one for about a week. As you can clearly see by the haphazard code I have below, I'm trying to create an SQL login system. It uses an SQLite file, and when I run the code to trouble shoot, no PHP errors pop up. I'm assuming this means it's a problem with the way I check the results, or my SQL. I, for one, am completely lost. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

```
session_start();

$user = strtolower(sqlite_escape_string($_POST['username']));
$pass = strtolower(sqlite_escape_string($_POST['password']));

$db = sqlite_open('my DB.sqlite', 0666, $sqlerr);

$query = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USER = '$user' AND PASS = '$pass'", $sqlerr);
$result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);

if (count($result) == 1) {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
    $_SESSION['loginFail'] = false;
    $_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['username'];
}

if ($sqlerr != null) {
    $_SESSION['sqlerr'] = $sqlerr;
}

if (!$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    $_SESSION['loginFail'] = true;
}

sqlite_close($db);
header("Location: index.php");
exit();
```

(Also, sorry if I forgot any information. I've not posted a StackOverflow question in a while.)

Comment: Be aware that the [`sqlite_`](http://php.net/ref.sqlite) family of functions is being converted to an *optional* extension as of PHP 5.4.  This could mean that the functions might not be available in places.  You should probably switch to [PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or the [SQLite3](http://php.net/book.sqlite3) extension.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but storing passwords as plain text in the database is a major security concern. Using a key derivation function like PBKDF2, bcrypt, or scrypt is quite easy, and will *massively* improve the safety of the passwords in case of an information disclosure attack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
$query = sqlite_query($db, "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM USERS WHERE USER = '$user' AND PASS = '$pass'", $sqlerr);
$result = sqlite_fetch_all($query, SQLITE_ASSOC);

if (count($result) == 1) {
```

You are asking for a count of rows from the database, which will be something like `1`, then you retrieve this result and put it into an array (`$result`), then count the number of entries in `$result`. The result of `count($result)` will always be exactly 1.

You need to either compare the *value* that is returned from the database or use `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT COUNT(*)`